# Oracle TNS problems?

Tags: database, oracle, listener

I have an error ? My pl/Sql Developer says my oracle database cannot find the service descriptor But when I Do a check the listener I get this error.

```
LSNRCTL> start
Starting tnslsnr: please wait...

Service OracleOraDb10g_home1TNSListener already running.
TNS-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error
 TNS-00530: Protocol adapter error



LSNRCTL> status
Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP
TNS-12541: TNS:no listener
 TNS-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error
  TNS-00511: No listener
   32-bit Windows Error: 61: Unknown error
```

the content of my listener.ora is

```
SID_LIST_LISTENER =
  (SID_LIST =
    (SID_DESC =
      (GLOBAL_DBNAME = Oracle10g)
      (ORACLE_HOME = D:\oracle\product\10.2.0\db_1)
      (SID_NAME = ORCL)
    )
  )

LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))
  )
```

and 
the tnsnames.ora content is this

```
# tnsnames.ora Network Configuration File: D:\oracle\product\10.2.0\db_1\NETWORK\ADMIN\tnsnames.ora
# Generated by Oracle configuration tools.

VMOBILE =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVICE_NAME = orcl)
    )
  )

VMOBILEMASTER =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVICE_NAME = ORCL)
    )
  )

ORCL =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = SHARED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = ORCL)
    )
  )

EXTPROC_CONNECTION_DATA =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SID = PLSExtProc)
      (PRESENTATION = RO)
    )
  )
```

Please I have a deadline for these evening. Please help.

Comment: Please post your SQLNET.ORA file too.  This could be part of the problem.   I've seen this erro when this file is not configured correctly.

Answer (score 2):

This is probably a configuration issue, which means it is difficult for us to solve remotely.  The two things you need to check are

1. The entries in your `LISTENER.ORA` file match your `TNSNAMES.ORA` file
2. The information in your `hosts` file is correct.

Is this a local or a remote database you're attempting to connect to?

**edit**

The hosts file (in a windows environment) is in somewhere like

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32\drivers\etc
```

Obviously it depends on how your environment is set up (different drive letter or whatever).

**edit**

You need the `GLOBAL_DBNAME` in the listener file to match the `SERVICE_NAME` in the tnsnsames file i.e. ORCL

Comment: I have tried the host files and it is setup correctly. CAn you help review the TNSname.ora file and LISTENER.ORA I posted above is it in order.

Answer (score 0):

The error is probably in the `listener.ora` file. Try replacing `localhost` in the line reading `(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))` with the name OR the ip number of the server where the listener is running on.

Comment: I have tried your suggestion still having the same error.


LSNRCTL> start
Starting tnslsnr: please wait...

Service OracleOraDb10g_home1TNSListener already running.
TNS-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error
 TNS-00530: Protocol adapter error

Comment: What if you do a `lsnrctl reload`

Answer (score 0):

I'd replace localhost with whatever ipconfig tells you is the IP address you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this error can happen in a variety of cases.

1. The Oracle database service (OracleServiceXE or whatever edition you are using) is not actually running.
2. The user was trying to run the TNSListener service under a non-administrator account, preventing it from registering the associated Windows service.
3. There was a conflict due to more than one ORACLE_HOME on the machine.
4. There is nothing wrong with the service or configuration settings, but the TNSListener service won't start successfully until the Windows server has been restarted.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved this error message today by running *LSNRCTL start* from cmd.exe, started "as Administrator".

I have 'localhost' server in listener.ora and in tnsnames.ora. Also i have SQLNET.AUTHENTICATION_SERVICES = (NONE) in sql.ini

Before I go trying use LSNRCTL.EXE, I haven't listener servise in windows services list. *LSNRCTL start* command from administrator's cmd make it for me.