# Getting ORA-12560 with Oracle Express 10g

Tags: oracle, oracle-xe, ora-12560

I started to receive this error while I`m using C# with Oracle 10g.

`ORA-12560` and I really need to solve it as I`m running out of time on my grad project.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your listener is running. If it is, try restarting it and re-registering your database with it (through sqlplus as sysdba, type the command `alter system register;`). Also, make sure that if you run a local firewall you have allowed the port 1521 for incoming traffic (or your custom port if you have changed this).

In Windows the listener is a service, prefixed with the oracle home name + TNSListener.
In Linux, set your oracle home environment and type:

```
lsnrctl stop
lsnrctl start
```

Comment: alter database register; didn`t work ... ORA-01900: LOGFILE keyword expected.

Comment: Sorry, `alter system register;` is the correct command to reregister the instance with the listener.

Comment: I`ve been able to solve the error, well I don`t know exactly how did I solve it ...

Answer (score 0):

ORA-12560 is a configuration issue.  This makes it difficult to diagnose remotely.  I have answered a similar question on SO before.  my advice is general enough that it should help you too.  [Find out more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2736377/oracle-tns-problems/2736518#2736518).

If it doesn't you'll need to post more details of your `listener.ora`, `tnsnames.ora` and  perhaps your `hosts` files.

**edit**

> "All the files are hosted here:"

Hmmmm.  Both `listener.ora` and`tnsnames.ora` reference `HOST = SIKAS-TOSH` but server is not included in the `hosts` file.

**edit 2**

> "the Oracle 10g Express Edition is
>   installed on my PC"

If your database is on your PC then the files on some web-server are irrelevant.  It is the `listener.ora` and`tnsnames.ora` *on your PC* which matter.  Those versions of the file need to reference  `HOST = localhost` or else your `hosts` needs to include  `SIKAS-TOSH` as an alias for 127.0.0.1.

Comment: forgot to mention, the Oracle 10g Express Edition is installed on my PC.

Comment: @sikas - You are the one with the deadline to meet, not us.  So if you want help from us you need to give us *all* the relevant info.

Comment: @APC: all the files exists on my PC in the Oracle directory. I`ve just uploaded them for you to examine them for me. SIKAS-TOSH is my computer name, I`ve added it to the hosts file 127.0.0.1    SIKAS-TOSH, but still the same problem.

Comment: @APC: I have changed the host in both listener.ora and tnsnames.ora, but still no success...

Comment: @APC: I`ve been able to solve the error, well I don`t know exactly how did I solve it ...

Answer (score 0):

I have unintalled and re-installed the oracle 10g many times as well as the ODAC112011beta, last time I didn`t install the `ODAC112011beta`, instead, I used the `Oracle.DataAccess.Client` file found in the `C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\10.2.0\server\BIN\Oracle.DataAccess.dll` ... then I started the service from `START->All Programs->Oracle Database 10g Express Edition->Start Database` as administrator ... now I can connect to the Oracle through C# ... I hope I face no more problems